# Bootstrap - Separate section into multiple sections and apply background image?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been experimenting with bootstrap and I think it's great. However, I've come to an issue that I would love to be able to apply this style, but do not know how to properly do so. What I want is for a section to be split into 2 halves (side by side) - one section has text and content and the other has an image. I know how to achieve this with bootstrap using containers/rows/columns, but I want to remove the borders and margins from the second section so that the image I set in there will take up the full space. It is difficult for me to describe in writing exactly what I want to I have attached a screenshot to depict what I mean.

Please refer to the "OTHER EXPERTISE" and "AMAZING PORTFOLIO" sections in screenshot..

[image: Website Mockup]

Comment: Sir, give code also :) So we can have a better understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: So, what you want to do is make those 2 pages look like the main page?  Was this a real question or an attempt at SPAM?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all your trying to do is make that other section full width? In that case just set the container width to 100%